# How to quickly drop a database table content using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using `Spring-data-jpa` with `CrudRepository` to persist data in a `postgres` db.

On a daily basis I want to renew the full db content, which means detele all data in a specific table first.

The repository offers a method `dao.deleteAll()`, but that lasts very long as I have about 500k entries.

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can execute native sql query on entity manager, and truncate your database

```
String sql = "TRUNCATE tbl_name;";
entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TRUNCATE` command is much faster on large tables because it simply nukes the files at the file system level, whereas `DELETE` marks each record as free without reducing file size, with any triggers defined on them being run.

Comment: How could I use `truncate` with hibernate/HQL, if possible?

Comment: Just note that on some databases you cannot use truncate if there are foreign keys defined, even if there are actually no actual data rows.